# Convert Latin letters to its corresponding English alphabet in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, apply, latin

I have a dataframe in pandas that contains restaurants name in it, but the problem is some restaurants name which include Latin letters eg é in Cafe, â in Yauatcha Pâtisserie are all encoded by the pandas differently for eg Yauatcha Pâtisserie was encoded by pandas as

`Yauatcha PÃ\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢tisserie`

There are different types of restaurant name containing different Latin letter which are encoded by pandas differently. Is there any way to get the Latin letter back or its English equivalent back?

You can download the dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13pFIOzyjDnefKcIWIgwwyK_9ZB3x-oUh).
I tried using the unicode library of python but that does not seem to be working.
Here is what I have tried :

```
import pandas as pd
import unidecode
df = pd.read_csv(r"stod.csv", encoding='latin1')
df['name'].apply(unidecode.unidecode)
```

So is there any way to get back the latin alphabet back from this gibberish

`Yauatcha PÃ\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢tisserie`

Note: I tried all possible suggestions for the solution to this question and none of that worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried using ```'utf-8'``` as encoding?

Comment: Yes I did that still gives me that gibberish

Comment: I dont think that is a latin alphabet. How did you obtain this data? It seems like scraping with BeautifulSoup. Either way it is gibberish

Comment: The data was scraped from zomato website and the restaurants name in the website were listed as Café and so on

Comment: I just checked: the French letter `â` has ASCII code 226, so there's no need for diificult encoding, neither for `é` (ASCII code 233).

Comment: @Dominique ASCII codes range from 0-127. 128-255 vary by code page used.

Comment: That dataset is garbage.  There is no reason for a single `â` to convert to such a long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a multiple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). I can revert it (see `demoji(x)` function in the following script). For the sake of completeness, `moji(x)` function shows the mojibake mechanism:

```
def demoji(x):
    global ii
    try:
      y = x.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
      ii += 1
    except:
      y = x
      ii = -ii
    return y

def moji(x):
    return x.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1','backslash replace')

xx = 'PÃ\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢tisserie'
zz = xx

print("values xx and zz (initial): {}".format(repr(xx)))
ii = 0
while ii >= 0:
    xx = demoji(xx)

yy = xx
print("values xx and yy after {} demoji(xx) iterations: {}".format(-ii,repr(xx)))
for i in range(-ii):
    yy = moji(yy)

print("values yy and zz after {}   moji(yy) iterations are equal: {}".format(-ii, yy==zz))
```

**Result:** `.\SO\55721108.py`

> ```
> values xx and zz (initial): 'PÃ\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x83Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x83Ã\x82Â\x82Ã\x83Â\x82Ã\x82Â¢tisserie'
> values xx and yy after 7 demoji(xx) iterations: 'Pâtisserie'
> values yy and zz after 7   moji(yy) iterations are equal: True
> ```